# Entity Mapping - Manytomany or OneToMany

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 simple tables as follows:

### Property

id
value

### Uid_property

id
property_id

Each row in uid_property is unique. A property can be assigned to multiple properties.

What is the best way to map this in hibernate? I am trying to decide whether this is onetomany or manytomany. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you'll have to think the problem through. In order to have a `ManyToMany`, you need to have both tables hold references to each other. You have a `property_id` in `Uid_property`, so there can be many `Uid_property` records with the same `property_id`, but you do not have anything that allows `Property` to reference `Uid_property`.

From the `Uid_property` entity point of view there can be `Many` records for `One` `Property`. In order to reproduce the database in JPA you could simply write the following code:

```
@Entity
public class Property {
    @Id @GeneratedValue private Long id;
}
@Entity
public class Uid_property {
    @Id @GeneratedValue private Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    Property property;
}
```

This would produce the following tables:

> create table Property (id bigint not null, primary key (id))
>
> create table Uid_property (id bigint not null, property_id bigint, primary key (id))

This matches what you have said, but there is an efficiency problem. If several `Uid_property` records are retrieved, duplicate `Property` entites are created:

```
List<Uid_property> pl = em.createQuery("select up from Uid_property up", Uid_property.class).getResultList();
pl.forEach(uid_p->{ System.out.println(uid_p + ":" + uid_p.getProperty()); });
```

Gives:

> model.Uid_property@5b58ed3c:**model.Property@592e843a**
> model.Uid_property@24faea88:**model.Property@592e843a**

It would be more efficient if there was one `Property` that referenced many `Uid_property` entities.

```
@Entity
public class Property {
    @Id @GeneratedValue private Long id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="property")
    private Set<Uid_property> uid_properties;
}
// This hasn't changed
@Entity
public class Uid_property {
    @Id @GeneratedValue private Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    private Property property;
}
```

Now getting the entities from the database is more efficient. Properties can be joined to `Uid_properties`:

```
List<Property> pl = em.createQuery("select distinct p from Property p left join fetch p.uid_properties", Property.class).getResultList();
pl.forEach(p->{ System.out.println(p + ":" + p.getUid_properties()); });
```

Which gives a single `Property` with a `Set` of uid_properties for the same database schema.

> model.Property@61078690:[model.Uid_property@37ebc9d8, model.Uid_property@1cb3ec38]